# Led Ceiling Driver Box - attached or NOT to wood structure?

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting

For a Recessed Slim LED 4" round light, can the Driver Box lay inside the ceiling, NOT attached to anything or is it Ontario Electrical Code to be screwed to a wood structure i.e. a 2x4 ?? Thanks!

Comment: I do not specifically know the answer to your problem, but generally, connections cannot be made where they cannot be accessed (afterwards).  Also the driver box is essentially a power supply, and if it gives off too much heat could cause a confined area to heat up.

Comment: Can you link the product in question? Sorry to put you to the trouble, the answer is not generic.

Comment: @mongo : For the accessibility to the box, I know they are to the Electrical Code. The LED trim (the part showing) on the ceiling has 2 spring loaded that hold on the  ceiling (top), it takes 5 seconds to pull it out or put it in. They are very easy and nice to install.

Comment: @Harper: Here is a link to product as requested: https://www.contrastlighting.com/Publication/Technical/FT_PROF40_EN.pdf

Comment: Please Note: that the accessory (Mounting plate) in the document (link) above does not come with the product and is not needed. I just need to know if the driver (box) must be attached to wood structure or can it let be standing free on the drywall of ceiling, to pass the Ontario Code. Thanks

Comment: I installed almost 60 LED 4" recessed lights in my house, i used strain-relief clamps for the wires and twisted them well inside the box which also has the Power supply integrated. i shoved the steel box in the ceiling void without fixing as you may need to pull it in the future to replace it in case necessary. so far all seems good.